# behavior of external executable

Tags: java, api

I am currently writing a program in JAVA that examines the behavior of external executable. One of the requirements is to observe the file operations of the external executable in real time (check if the executable creates/ deletes/modifies any file). I tried to find a suitable API in java to help me do this though it was not possible to find one. I have found the Class FileAlterationObserver which is not suitable for my program since you have to specify manually all the directories you want to monitor.

I was wondering if any of you knows a good API to use?

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without java, you could use the linux `lsof` command to list the open files in the system. Alternatively, and with Java, you can use libnotify, but you will need to specify the folders. I can't see any other way of doing this with pure java.

EDIT @Keppil linked you to the [file change notification API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) that looks way more suitable than libjnotify. I wasn't aware it existed!